# Copy Azure Mobile Service Instance

Tags: azure, mobile, azure-mobile-services, azure-cli

I'm using Azure Mobile Services for my mobile app backend. I'd like to make a copy of my current service (scripts, api, schedulers, tables etc.) for Test and Production environments. Is there an automated/scripted process to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this point the answer is no. You have to create a new Mobile Service, recreate all the tables using the cli or web portal, copy over the database schema, copy over the scripts, and reconfigure any schedulers.

Once you have done that it's easier to maintain the workflow from dev->staging->production if you use a db schema tool like Flyway or Visual Studio. Also connect the git repos for the different services so that you can pull from dev and push to staging and then production.

Comment: Thanks I thought this might be the case. Lots of room to improve this process. It'd be nice to have a button to clone the service instance.

Comment: Yeah, this is a real bummer. I found out recently the hard way. But the good news is that it CAN be done, albeit with more work than it should be.